# What is the diferrence between $(objs): %.o : %.cpp and $(objs): $(objs:.o=.cpp) in Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation

I have add.c sub.c in current directory and compile them through makefile.

I do the following:

> program 1:
>
> > objs=$(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp))
> >
> > $(objs): %.o : %.cpp
> >
> > g++ -o $@ -c $<
>
> program 2:
>
> > objs=$(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp))
> >
> > $(objs): $(objs:.o=.cpp)
> >
> > g++ -o $@ -c $<

Program 1 compiles successfully. But program 2  gets the following command:

> g++ -o sub.o -c **sub.cpp**
>
> g++ -o add.o -c **sub.cpp**

So what's the diferrence between these two programs?

Comment: Is that intentional that compiling `sub.cpp` the second time overwrites `add.o`  Or is that a typo?

Comment: Read [GNU make: Multiple Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html). Especially the first and the last sentence.

Comment: @Matt. The document is quite useful! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule in makefile 1 is equivalent to

```
sub.o: sub.cpp
    g++ -o $@ -c $<

add.o: add.cpp
    g++ -o $@ -c $<
```

which works correctly.

The rule in makefile 2 expands to

```
sub.o add.o: sub.cpp add.cpp
    g++ -o $@ -c $<
```

Which says that *each* of those two targets depends on *both* source files. Note that the [automatic variable `$<`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) expands to the first prerequisite, which in this case is `sub.cpp`. So that's the only source file that the rule uses, even when attempting to build `add.o`.